# Is it possible to have such a regex?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string like this:
`124:111,120:444,103:504,494:120,404:111,200:100,`

I will use replace() and let's say I want to select
`124:111,120:444,103:504,494:120,404:111,**200:100,**`
without actually defining `200:100,` but instead having it to work like this:

Define only :100, regex selects everything to the left until "," approaches and everything to the right including first "," => 200:100,

Is it possible to have such a regex? Thanks for any information

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible.

Comment: This would be a lot easier with split and no regex at all

Comment: (?<=[,]).*(?=[\,]) almost there, just got lost with adding :100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Regex

```
,?(\d*?):100
```

Will match `:100` and capture the digits before that:

```js
const regex = /,?(\d*?):100/gm;
const sourceValue = '124:111,120:444,103:504,494:120,404:111,200:100,';
const match = regex.exec(sourceValue);

console.log(match[1]);
// 200
```

---

##### `split()`

Another option is to split on `,`, then check if the right side has the value you're searching for

```js
const sourceValue = '124:111,120:444,103:504,494:120,404:111,200:100,';
const searchValue = 100;

sourceValue.split(',').forEach(p => {
    const [ l, r ] = p.split(':');
    if (+r === searchValue) {
        console.log(`Found searchValue\n\nLeft\t\t${l}\nRight\t\t${r}\nOriginal\t${p}`);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `replace()` you could do it this way in my opinion.

1. Define the regex pattern and matches any sequence of characters that does not include a comma

   ```
   const pattern = /[^,]*:100,/;
   ```
2. Use `match()` to find a match of the pattern in the input string:

   ```
   const match = string.match(pattern);
   ```
3. Check if a match is found

   ```
   if (match) {
    const result = match[0];
     console.log(result);
   } else {
     console.log("Pattern not found");
   }
   ```